# Simple onblur JavaScript to get data from another list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

Looking for a simple JavaScript code to populate data from another SharePoint list in nintex form

I have two list

The main list " Leave request"
Which has following column:
Leave Details...
Personal Details :
ID number,
Name and Surname,
Email Address

Second List
"Personal Details list"
Name & surname,
Id Number,
Email

On the form, initiator has to type their ID Number and automatically the form has to populate the name & surname and Email address

How can I do that using javascript/ or anything else that can help
The form is in nintex forms

I treid searching for javaScript code but I don't seem to understand any of the codes as I am new in javascript

Appreciate any solution and help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use SPServices

i cant tell you how to use SPServices since it should be initialized and it has some dependencies. 
You can see qualified documentation in the following link

http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation

after than the following code is to get items of Announcements list where title is stackoverflow
(http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems)

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' />stackoverflow</ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
       $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

       //this part to loop over the items 
       //it gets title column value of current indexed item

       var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
       $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
     });
    }
```

});

now you can do whatever you want